# Galilean spacetime

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a picture of Galilean spacetime, like this one from Penrose's book "the road to reality".

[image]

I was able to draw the "planes" one stacked over another, but I didn't manage to draw satisfactorily some paths (the arrowed lines in Penrose picture) in such a way as to give the illusion that they go through the planes. (I actually don't need the paths to be arrowed, nor I need the dashed curves around the planes that can be seen in Penrose's picture).

Here's how I started the code:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1cm,0cm)}, y={(0cm,1cm)}, z={(3.85mm, 3.85mm)}]% default z value: (-3.85mm,-3.85mm)


\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
    \draw[fill=white]  (0, 0) rectangle (4, 3);
\end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0.5]
    \draw[fill=white]  (0, 0) rectangle (4, 3);
\end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=1]
    \draw[fill=white]  (0, 0) rectangle (4, 3);
\end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=1.5]
    \draw[fill=white] (0, 0) rectangle (4, 3);
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 9):

In order to get an orthographic projection, one can use `tikz-3dplot`. Then you need to develop the picture step by step by always drawing the stretches between the planes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{110}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,declare function={a1=0.2;b1=-0.1;
    a2=0.3;b2=-0.1;a3=-0.2;b3=0.3;a4=0.4;b4=0.1;}]
 \path (1.5,-1,0) coordinate (p1)  (-1,0.5,0) coordinate (p2) 
  (1,1,0) coordinate (p3) (-0.5,-0.5,0) coordinate (p4);
 \foreach \Y in {1,...,4}
 {
 \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
  {\draw ($(p\X)+({(\Y-1)*a\X},{(\Y-1)*b\X},\Y-1)$) -- ($(p\X)+(\Y*a\X,\Y*b\X,\Y)$);}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\Y]
  \draw[fill=white,fill opacity=0.9] (-3,{-3+sin((\Y-1)*90/1.5)}) rectangle ++ (6,6);
 \end{scope}
  }
 \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
  {\draw[-latex] ($(p\X)+({4*a\X},{4*b\X},4)$) -- ($(p\X)+(5.5*a\X,5.5*b\X,5.5)$);}  
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can also add an animation to make the concept of time slicing a bit clearer (?). (It isn't necessarily a purely Galilean concept, though.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{recycle bounding box/.style={%
execute at end picture={%
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\tikz@bbox@figbb@#1{%
(\the\pgf@picminx,\the\pgf@picminy) rectangle (\the\pgf@picmaxx,\the\pgf@picmaxy)}\relax}},
execute at begin picture={%
\ifcsname tikz@bbox@figbb@#1\endcsname
 \edef\figbb{\csname tikz@bbox@figbb@#1\endcsname}
 \path \figbb;
\fi}}}  

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\foreach \Z in {1,...,40}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[recycle bounding box=A]
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{110}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,declare function={a1=0.2;b1=-0.1;
    a2=0.3;b2=-0.1;a3=-0.2;b3=0.3;a4=0.4;b4=0.1;}]
 \path (1.5,-1,0) coordinate (p1)  (-1,0.5,0) coordinate (p2) 
  (1,1,0) coordinate (p3) (-0.5,-0.5,0) coordinate (p4);
 \foreach \Y in {1,...,\Z}
 {
 \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
  {\draw ($(p\X)+({0.1*(\Y-1)*a\X},{0.1*(\Y-1)*b\X},{0.1*(\Y-1)})$) 
    -- ($(p\X)+(0.1*\Y*a\X,0.1*\Y*b\X,0.1*\Y)$);}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0.1*\Y]
  \draw[fill=white,fill opacity=0.5] (-3,{-3+sin((\Y-1)*90/1.5)}) rectangle ++ (6,6);
  \ifodd\Y
   \marmot[rotate=90,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm,leftstep]
  \else
   \marmot[rotate=90,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm,rightstep]
  \fi 
 \end{scope}
  }
 \ifnum\Z=40
 \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
  {\draw[-latex] ($(p\X)+({4*a\X},{4*b\X},4)$) -- ($(p\X)+(5.5*a\X,5.5*b\X,5.5)$);}  
 \fi  
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you waiting for such questions to pull off your tricks . Excellent job.

Comment: @Diaa Thanks! No, I am not waiting for them (nor are they waiting for me;-). Conceptually this is, like many other questions, a repeating theme. However, I do not know how to avoid the repetition, it seems to be inevitable by the design of this site. An answer consisting only of a sentence "You have to draw things step by step according to their visibility." may not be what the OP expects (for good reasons, of course).

Comment: I am just joking. You are doing a great job supporting the tikz community.

Comment: @Diaa I wasn't taking this as a criticism at all. Just wanted to say that in principle one could think of a different approach when answering these questions. In fact, I tried to write some library which automatizes some of these steps. However, it might be that all of this is a bit futile since actually pdf viewers can do that for you, see section 13.6.43D View of [this document](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#G7.3998969). It is conceivable that in the future Ti*k*Z or a successor just accesses these features.